# Why is it unable to update with Put?

Tags: http, go, put

I am currently trying to update my data using PUT and REST, I get no error when executing the command `curl -v http://192.168.1.148:8080/customColors -XPUT -d '{"Id":9}' | jq` but when checking the JSON the content is not updated. The current path being used here is `localhost:8080/customColors`, I am just expecting to update the id of the first Object below are the code concerned:

the struct:

```
type CustomColor struct {
    Id int
    Title string
    Created string //time.Time
    Body [4]float64
    
}
```

the list of structs:

```
var l = []*CustomColor{
    &CustomColor{
    Id:1,
    Title:"CustomColor",
    Created:"10/11/2020",
    Body:[4]float64{
                0.4,0.3,0.1,1,
            },
        },
        &CustomColor{
            Id:2,
            Title:"CustomColor",
            Created:"10/11/2020",
            Body:[4]float64{
                        0.1,0.5,0.1,1,
                    },
                },
                &CustomColor{
                    Id:3,
                    Title:"CustomColor",
                    Created:"10/11/2020",
                    Body:[4]float64{
                                0.7,0.8,0.2,1,
                            },
                        },
    
    }
```

the code inside the function directly related to the handler:

```
if r.Method == http.MethodPut{
        id := 1
        fmt.Println("PUT",r.URL.Path)
    reg := regexp.MustCompile(`/customColors`) // verify correect path can play around with this
    g := reg.FindAllStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path, -1)

    if len(g) != 1 {
        fmt.Println("1")
        http.Error(w, "Invalid URL", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    if len(g[0]) != 1 {
        fmt.Println("2")
        fmt.Println(len(g[0]))
        http.Error(w, "Invalid URL", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    idStr := g[0][0]


    fmt.Println("got id", idStr)

    update(id, w, r)
    return
    }
```

the other chunk of codes :

```
func update(id int, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

var f CustomColor
var iR io.Reader
iR = r.Body
err := json.NewDecoder(iR).Decode(&f)

if err !=  nil{
fmt.Println(err)
}


err = updateCColor(id, &CustomColor{})

if err != ObjectNotFound{
http.Error(w, "Object not found", http.StatusNotFound)
return
}

if err != nil{
    http.Error(w, "Object not found", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
    }
    



}

func updateCColor(id int, c*CustomColor) error{
_, pos, err := findObject(id)

if err != nil{
    return err
}

c.Id = id
l[pos] = c
fmt.Println(l[pos])
return nil 
}

var ObjectNotFound = fmt.Errorf("Object not found")

func findObject(id int) (*CustomColor, int, error){
for i, o := range l{
    if o.Id == id {
        return o, i, nil
    }
}
return nil, -1,  ObjectNotFound
}
```

The output I get from what I am printing are:

```
PUT /customColors
got id /customColors
```

the output I get from the put command is:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 192.168.1.148...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.1.148 (192.168.1.148) port 8080 (#0)
> PUT /customColors HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.148:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 8
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
} [8 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 8 out of 8 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2020 02:34:42 GMT
< Content-Length: 17
<
{ [17 bytes data]
100    25  100    17  100     8   2428   1142 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3571
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.148 left intact
(23) Failed writing body
* Closing connection 0
```

Thank you all for your time and effort

Comment: @MuffinTop I've edited the post

Comment: The id is 1 per second line of Go code in the question. The update function returns `ObjectNotFound` because there is no value with `id == 1`. It looks like the code in the handler is intended to return a 404 status for `ObjectNotFound`, but the actual logic returns a 500 status. That's what you see in output. Things to fix 1) write logic to parse the id from the request 2) fix the error handling in request handler. You want `if err == ObjectNotFound {` in the if statement.

Comment: @MuffinTop thanks, I'm sorry for asking though since I'm quite new to go do you have a little. example of the logic that can be written here?

Comment: I gave the code to fix the error handling in my previous comment. I don't understand how you want to get the id from the request, so I cannot help there.

Comment: @CamilleBasbous Give us something we can execute https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  You're close, you appear to have the curl command, and the important code.  Build one go file we can run  that shows your problem, and show the curl command against it .

Comment: @MuffinTop oh I saw what you are talking about, I changed it the id of the customColor. Then I've hit the command curl -v http://192.168.1.148:8080/customColors -XPUT -d '{"Title":"CustomColor","Created":"10/11/2020","Body":[0.1,5,0.1,1]}' | jq. The problem is the output i get is {"Id":1,"Title":"","Created":"","Body":[0,0,0,0]} i do get a HTTP/1.1 200 OK though

Comment: I fixed it thanks both of you for your time

Comment: @velkor i plan on modifying it in later phase this isn't its final form yes I will be getting the id on the request